# Android: Failure delivering result info on create scaled bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I want to create a scaled bitmap so I have this meethod:

```
Options var7 = new Options();
            var7.inPreferredConfig = Config.ARGB_8888;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(this.file.getAbsolutePath(), var7);
            Bitmap b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 120, 120, false);
            this.bmp = b;
```

The above code fails on create scaled bitmap with an error message of failure delivering result info (data = Intent has extras).
what am I doing wrong.

Complete Error Message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.myscan.capture.Activity4}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.myscan.capture/com.myscan.capture.Activity4}:
```

Comment: Can you put complete error message here?

Comment: Complete error message updated